# What is the use of blue dot in remix ide?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

When I usually write my code in remix solidity a blue dot usually appeared on the left side with code line's numbers as follows:

[image]

Kindly tell me what is it for?

Thanks for the help :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a [breakpoint](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugger.html#breakpoints). Remix has a [debugging](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugger.html) feature that helps you debug transactions and analyze them line by line.

You can toggle a breakpoint by clicking on the space on the left side of the line number